# Solr, exact word search for alphanumeric words

Tags: search, solr, search-engine

I want to configure my solr search engine so that I can get exact word searches, where words can have alphanumeric characters. I first tried with the following code

```
<field name="id" type="TextField" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="freq" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

When I try to post values using `java -jar post.jar vocab500.xml` 
I get the error:

```
SimplePostTool version 1.5
Posting files to base url http://localhost:8983/solr/update using content-type application/xml..
POSTing file vocab500.xml
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 Bad Request
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/update
```

I found some answers on Stackoverflow and changed the fieldname to `textgen`

```
<field name="id" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="freq" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

but I still got the same error.

Comment: Please provide error message from Solr log.

Comment: Along with complete error log, also let us know whether your schema file have field types defined as TextField/textgen.